# Is there an OR filter? - Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

is there any way of doing the following

```
Unicorn.objects.or_filter(magical=True).or_filter(unicorn_length=15).or_filter(skin_color='White').or_filter(skin_color='Blue')
```

where `or_filter` stands for an isolated match

---

I remember using something similar but cannot find the function anymore!

Help would be great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`Q` objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).