# Django’s filter() method joins parameters using an AND statement. Is there an alternative that uses OR?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I’m trying to write a Django query that returns objects that match *either* of two parameters.

If I do this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(parameter1=True, parameter2=True)
```

Then I only get objects that match *both* parameters.

What query can I use to select objects that match *either* parameter?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964540/is-there-an-or-filter-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. You just need to use special Q object.
As it is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Aha, thank you kindly. (I’d quibble over the idea that it’s simple, given that the section name contains the word “complex”, but it’s definitely the way to go — much appreciated.)